# How is Zn not a transition metal?

Tags: transition-metals, oxidation-state

A transition metal can be defined as an element that possesses an incomplete sub-level in one or more of its oxidization states. In the textbook I'm reading, it claims that zinc is not a transition metal because it has a full $d$-sub-level in all its oxidization states.

A quick google reveals that zinc has oxidization states $-2, 0, +1$, which means that zinc(with oxidization number $+1$) has an incomplete d-sub-level and *is* a  transition metal.

What's going on here? Is my textbook incorrect?

Comment: Zinc does not have an incomplete $d$ subshell, it does not use any of that subshell for valence orbitals and [even its heats of fusion and vaporization](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/123863/17175) betray a lack of typical transition-metal properties.  It just does not fit.  But hey, we still have scandium through copper in that period.

Comment: So is zinc just a special case? I would imagine cadmium should have these properties if not?

Comment: Cadmium isn't a transition metal either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zinc in the +1 oxidation state is $\text{[Ar]}3d^{10}4s^1$, and even in its highest, most common known oxidation state +2 (which the quoted values above seem to have forgotten) it's still $\text{[Ar]}3d^{10}$. No known zinc species in what we normally consider the realm of chemistry breaks that complete $3d^{10}$ subshell, and we would need a major revamp of our calculations and models if any ever does.  Moreover, the [thermophysical properties](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/123863/17175) of zinc also betray a loss of transition-metal character.  Zinc is just not a transition element.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to my question, I want to state $\ce{Zn}$ is not a transition metal also because of the [Aufbau Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle). According to the principle, electrons are removed from the subshell with the highest quantum number first. So in a case such as $\ce{Zn^2+}$, electrons are moved from the $4s$ subshells instead of the $d$-subshells. The $d$-subshell remains full.